# oracle vm instance, no matches found

Tags: linux, google-chrome, virtual-machine, oracle-linux

I am trying to launch chromium on `Oracle-Linux-8.9-2024.01.26-0` it is a vm i got from oracle, yet I get the following error

```
root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-121.0.6167.85/chrome-linux64/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libdrm.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Indeed if i try to install chromium or google chrome itself I get the error

```
[root@ilk testcases]# dnf install google-chrome-stable
Last metadata expiration check: 2:51:07 ago on Wed Feb 21 11:34:51 2024.
No match for argument: google-chrome-stable
Error: Unable to find a match: google-chrome-stable
[root@ilk testcases]# yum install google-chrome-stable
Last metadata expiration check: 2:51:22 ago on Wed Feb 21 11:34:51 2024.
No match for argument: google-chrome-stable
Error: Unable to find a match: google-chrome-stable
[root@ilk testcases]# yum install chromium
Last metadata expiration check: 2:51:32 ago on Wed Feb 21 11:34:51 2024.
No match for argument: chromium
Error: Unable to find a match: chromium
```

Note: before i ran this, i also did `yum update -y` or `yum update`

so nothing works on Oracle VM!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install chrome browser you can use two possible ways:

1. Direct download the browser. Just exec this command

   `yum localinstall https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm`
2. Install the google repo and then install the browser. For more detailed instruction you can check [this page](https://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-in-linux/)